# Sending a Javascript Variable to Flask Python Code without Form-Event

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a problem with Flask and Javascript. I want to use a website to control a minirobot with joysticks. I have found nippleJS (https://github.com/yoannmoinet/nipplejs) and included it to my website. I can print the joystick values to the web console, but i need those values at my pythonscript for the robot control. Can anybody help me please? Here is my code: HTML:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='nippleJS.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
        var joystickL = nipplejs.create({
            zone: document.getElementById('left'),
            mode: 'static',
            position: { left: '20%', top: '50%' },
            color: 'green',
            size: 200
            
        });
        

        var joystickR = nipplejs.create({
            zone: document.getElementById('right'),
            mode: 'static',
            position: { left: '80%', top: '50%' },
            color: 'red',
            size: 200,
            lockY: 1
        });

        joystickL.on('move', function (evt, nipple) {
            var dis = nipple.distance;
            var angle = nipple.angle.radian;
            var pos = nipple.position;
            console.log(dis);
            console.log(angle); </script>
```

And here is my Flask Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():

if request.method == 'POST':
    
    if request.form['btn'] == 'Demo Programme':
        return redirect(url_for('demo'))

    elif request.form['btn'] == 'Manuelle Steuerung':
        return redirect(url_for('steuerung'))

    elif request.form['btn'] == 'Erweiterte Optionen':
        return redirect(url_for('optionen'))



return render_template('home.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could use the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API to send a request to your server which has a JSON body holding the values.

Your `on("move")` could then look something like this.

```js
joystickL.on('move', function (evt, nipple) {
    const data = {
        "distance": nipple.distance,
        "radian": nipple.angle.radian,
        "position": nipple.position,
    }
    try {
        // call to your server with the correct host and username
        const response = await fetch("localhost:5000/your-endpoint", {
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.parse(data)
        })
        if(!response.ok){
            // your error handling here (if necessary)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

Depending on the frequency you need to send data e.g. you want more or less realtime data it would be better to use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). You might also wanna have a look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/).
I believe there also is a `socket.io` package specific for Flask as you need to adjust frontend and backend if you want to use WebSockets.